# Why can't python threads run again once they have finished?

Tags: python, multithreading

Assume the following simplest threading example

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def main():
    t = Thread(target=foo)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    sleep(100)
    t.start()

def foo():
    print "foo!"

main()
```

This attempts to run `t` twice.
The first time succeeds, but the second one throws an exception stating *"threads can only run once"*

This behavior makes no sense to me.
I would expect a finished thread to be ready to start again.

My question is **WHY** threads are not allowed to start again once they have finished?

---

This question got a "not clear what you're asking" vote - Please tell me what to explain better

This question got an "opinion based" vote. This is NOT opinion based. I am asking you to explain design decisions of python. I hope they didn't go by gut feeling. I'm pretty sure they didn't.

Comment: It would be impossible for code to decide whether the original execution ended or not, because if you kepp restarting the thread they may not "catch" the precise  moment when  the original  stopped and might think the original execution is still ongoing. Avoiding this requires handling some tagging etc which complicates the implementation. Besides OS thread cannot be restarted so the current API is closer to the real thing.

Comment: start() must be called at most once per thread object. watch doc here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start

Comment: I haven't voted to close the question, but design decisions are still opinion-based even if they're not based on gut; do you choose versatility or performance (for example)? Maybe there are reasons to choose either, but the designers preferred one over the other because of their opinion on which was more important. Questions asking for design decisions/reasoning of language creators are almost always considered off-topic on Stack Overflow, historically.

Comment: I think the practical answer is pretty simple -- Python Threads, like a lot of Python APIs, are straightforward 1:1 wrappers around the analogous C-based APIs provided by the host operating system, and in most (probably all?) OS's, a thread that has exited cannot be restarted (you have to spawn a new thread instead), therefore Python's thread class inherits that behavior.  (note that if you do want to "restart a thread", you can get that behavior fairly easily by programming the thread not to exit when its work is done, but rather to wait for more work -- i.e. a simple threadpool)

Answer (score 0):

The deeper reason why you can't run the same thread more than one time is the same as the reason why you can't go on the same trip more than once. Even if you stay in all of the same places, and do all of the same things when you go back a second time, it's still a *different* trip.

A thread (a real *thread*, not the `Thread` object that gives you the ability to start and manage the thread) is an execution of your code (i.e., a "trip" through your code).